# Datetime2 conversion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

can anyone know why a datetime2 sql server field isn't correctly retreived in coldfusion?

For example the value '2016-06-23 00:00:00.0000000' in sql server when retrieved in coldfusion become {ts '2016-06-21 00:00:00'} (a difference of 2 days).

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it is because of the precision difference. You could lower the precision of datetime2 to match the coldfusion one.

Comment: Please show the code that illustrates this difference.